# Store https passwords with cygwin's Git

Tags: windows, git, passwords, cygwin, bitbucket

I am using Cygwin and Git. Every time I push/pull to a repo on Bitbucket with a https url I am asked to enter a password. 
Is there a way to store these credentials (like with ssh-keys)?

I tried to install [Windows Credential Store for Git](http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/) but I can't get it to work with cygwin's Git.

Thanks!

**Update:**

I found my answer here: [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github)

Summarized:

Remember passwords for 15 minutes (default):

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

Remember passwords for 10 hours:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=36000'
```

Store passwords (didn't try this):

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Reset:

```
git config --unset --global credential.helper
```

Cim

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github)

Comment: next time if you find the answer, just write an answer to your own question (you can and it's a good practice) instead of writing editing the question to put the answer in

Comment: I tried the "store password" option and it worked, even after rebooting cygwin. Didn't try more.

Answer (score 31):

The way OP answered his own question is one way to go about it.

The *Windows Credential Store* project was discontinued in 2015. Its original author suggests to use [Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows), maintained by Microsoft. Their installer is focused on *Git for Windows*, however the program itself works well with Cygwin, you just have to install it manually.

Go the [GCMW's latest release](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/latest), download the zip file (not the installer), extract its contents (only `.dll` and `.exe` files are needed) to `C:\cygwin\usr\libexec\git-core\` for 32-bit Cygwin, or `C:\cygwin64\usr\libexec\git-core\` for 64-bit Cygwin. [Reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/146)

To get git to use GCMW, execute: `git config --global credential.helper manager`

To get GUI prompts for credentials, execute: `git config --global credential.modalprompt true`

If you want this to be a per-repository setting, remove the `--global` option.

Comment: A final tip, make sure to `chmod a+x *.{exe,dll}` after copying these files into `git-core`. Otherwise, you'll see an error like "'credential-manager' is not a git command" because git-credential-manager.exe isn't executable.

Comment: This solution works for MSYS2 as well. The path to dump the `*.dll` and `*.exe` in is `C:\msys64\usr\lib\git-core`.

Comment: GCMFW is now(or soon?) obsolete. The following tweaked solution works for the new cross-platform git-credential-manager-core. After moving all exe/dlls from the Git Credential Manager Core zip just use `git config --global credential.helper manager-core` The new utility is here: https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/releases

Comment: 2023 update: the solution still works, but you also have to copy *.config files apart from EXEs and DLLs.

Answer (score 19):

I made [Windows Credential Store](http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/) working with cygwin. The only thing that needs to be changed is global ~/.gitconfig file.

Change 'helper' value which can be found usually at the end of the file to the following:

```
[credential]
    helper = !'/cygdrive/C/Users/<YOUR-ACCOUNT-NAME>/AppData/Roaming/GitCredStore/git-credential-winstore.exe'
```

For an explanation, cygwin simply uses different paths and the value must follow the rules of course.

Comment: This is gold, thanks! Everyone make sure to install cygwins git (via the cygwin installer). Otherwise you will not get this solution to work.

Comment: Worked for me! But I'm using the more recent `git-credential-manager` and my path's slightly different: `!'/cygdrive/C/Users/<YOUR-ACCOUNT-NAME>/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft Git Credential Manager for Windows/git-credential-manager.exe'`

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Gene Pavlovsky's answer (and its comments):

We can **symlink** the .exe file to `/usr/libexec/git-core`, instead of installing a whole bunch of files directly into the folder.

1. install/extract [Git-Credential-Manager-Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/releases) (the current mainstream project) to any folder you like, e.g. `D:\path\to\gcm`
2. symlink `git-credential-manager.exe` to `/usr/libexec/git-core`:

   ```bash
   ln -s /cygdrive/d/path/to/gcm/git-credential-manager.exe /usr/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe
   ```

In this way we can keep `git-core` directory tidy, and make update / uninstall process easy.